# Angular dynamic localisation and facebook.sdk does not update the translation for the Like button

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, analytics

I have added the Facebook js-sdk as a directive in an angular app, I have a button the switch the pages language my problem is that the sdk does not update the text for the Like button, even after I removed the sdk and add a new one for the selected language. I ran the FB.XFBML.parse() to update the txt but it will keep on using the first selected language only after a page refresh would changes take place

***UPDATED CODE***
Now Using a service with ngrx when language change it will **replace** the Facebook SDK for that language and dispatches an event for any the page directives to remove all the tags/classes Facebook added on the like button element and clear its children. Everything works the button show up but its still in the first language selected it does not change language

Code Service

```
@Injectable()
export class FacebookService {
  constructor(private window: any, private document, private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    store.pipe(select(fromCore.getSelectedLang)).subscribe(lang => this.switchScript(lang));
    if (!this.window.fbAsyncInit) {
      this.window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
        this.window.FB.init({
          appId: environment.appId,
          autoLogAppEvents: true,
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: 'v4.0',
        });
      };
    }
  }

  switchScript(lang: string) {
    const langUrl = lang === 'ar' ? 'ar_AR' : 'en_US';
    const newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.id = 'facebook-sdk';
    newScript.async = true;
    newScript.src = `https://connect.facebook.net/${langUrl}/sdk.js`;

    const scriptTag = this.document.getElementById('facebook-sdk');
    if (scriptTag) {
      scriptTag.parentNode.replaceChild(newScript, scriptTag);
    } else {
      this.document.body.appendChild(newScript);
    }
    this.store.dispatch(SocialAction.UpdateTags({lang}));
  }    
}
```

Code Directive

```
@Directive({selector: '[lyxFacebook]'})
export class FacebookDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  tag$: Subscription;
  constructor(private window: any,private document, private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    this.tag$ = store.pipe(select(Core.getTagLang)).subscribe(lang=> this.update(lang));
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.window.FB) {
      this.window.FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
  }

  update(lang: string) {
    if (this.window.FB && lang) {
      const tags = this.document.getElementsByClassName('fb-like');
      if (tags && tags.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
          tags[i].removeAttribute('fb-xfbml-state');
          tags[i].removeAttribute('fb-iframe-plugin-query');
          tags[i].classList.remove('fb_iframe_widget');
          tags[i].innerHTML = '';
        }
        this.window.FB.XFBML.parse();
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.tag$) {
      this.tag$.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `FB.XFBML.parse` does not _update_ any social plugins that have already been rendered, it only looks for new `<div class="fb-XY">` elements that have not been parsed into social plugins yet. You need to replace the existing like button with such a template again, and then call the method. (Removing the `fb-xfbml-state="rendered"` attribute it places on the element might also work, but I have not tested it.)

Comment: I tried it and updated the code here to reflect the changes, but it did not work the language is still the very first language selected, I feel we are close but something is missing. The last thing I can think of is removing the final tag element added by Facebook "fb-root", and now with a clean slate I don't know what function reinitialize it back into view after adding the new local SDK

Comment: Guess that language switch won’t work by just changing out the SDK source … You’d have to re-initialize it, but I don’t know what it checks for to prevent that from happening twice perhaps, might be that you need to delete the global `FB` object first or something like that.